# How do I specify an encoding-independent string constant in the Windows API?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode, character-encoding

In C++, an ASCII string constant can be specified using the syntax `"string"`, and a Unicode string constant can be specified using the syntax `L"string"`. In the Windows API, the types of these string constants are called `LPCSTR` and `LPCWSTR` respectively. There's also the macro `LPCTSTR` to specify a string constant in whichever encoding the program was compiled for. Is there a similar syntax for string constants, where the string will be encoded in ASCII or Unicode depending on how the program was compiled?

Essentially I'm asking how to specify an `LPCTSTR` constant in C++. There has to be an easier way than using `#ifdef _UNICODE` and writing two versions of every line that needs a string constant.

Comment: IIRC, `_T("string")`

Comment: But use of these features is discouraged nowadays; safer to choose a compiler mode (preferably Unicode) and stick with it.

Comment: You can also use TEXT macro. TEXT("Hello")

Comment: I'm sorry to be "that guy", but a string can be Unicode regardless of the size of a character. UTF-8 is Unicode over 8-bit characters, and UTF-16 is Unicode over 16-bit characters. Neither guarantees that one physical character, regardless of its size, is one logical character.

Comment: Are you still coding for Windows 98? If not, use Unicode everywhere.

Comment: @zneak: it's a Windows question, so we're using Windows terminology.  The disconnect with modern usage is unfortunate, but it dates from a time before UTF-8 was invented.  At any rate, in the Windows API you have to use the wide-character ("Unicode") functions in order to use Unicode, because the narrow-character ("ANSI") functions don't support UTF-8, so it isn't entirely unreasonable in context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_T` or `TEXT` to define string literals.

e.g.

```
SomeOtherMethod( _T( "Hello" ) );

// Becomes either MyMethodA or MyMethodW.
MyMethod( TEXT( "Hello" ) );
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! Both `_T` and `TEXT` are equivalent, right?

Comment: Equivilent, yes.  But they belong to different APIs.  `_T()` is used by the C runtime, whereas `TEXT()` is used by the Win32 API.  Use the correct macro with the appropriate API, do not mix them.